# load website without images for more efficency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, performance

I have a chrome extension where where when I press a button it goes to a url where It is going to click on buttons and search for things.  I want it to run as fast as possible so I want to go to the url and not load any images so It can run faster I tried

```
$('img').remove();
```

in the console of the website 
( https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all )

which does remove all the images but I want to know if there is a better way to do this because It seems as if I have to load the website when I go to it and then it will remove all the images.

Is there anyway to make it go to this website but somehow remove the images before it loads the website to save time?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a userscript in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey (or custom stylesheet in an addon like Stylish) that ensures that `img`s always get `display: none`. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Images
// @namespace    CertainPerformance
// @version      1
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
img {
  display: none !important
}
`;
```

Install this userscript, open your browser's Network tab, then navigate to somewhere on stackoverflow.com that you haven't visited before - that is, somewhere where your browser hasn't loaded the posters' images before. With this userscript, you'll see that the avatar image requests to `www.gravatar.com` never get sent out - nothing unwanted gets downloaded.

Note that the

```
// @run-at       document-start
```

is important - without that, the userscript will run *after* initial page load, which will give the browser a few milliseconds to start downloading the images in preparation to display them, before the script runs.

Of course, customize as you need - change the

```
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
```

to whichever URLs you want to hide images on.

That said, if you want to run an *automatic script* on that other page to gather data, it would probably be more efficient to use plain requests like with `fetch`, and then parse the response *text* into a document, and search through the document, instead of loading up a whole new page in your browser.

Comment: I tried document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  img {
     display: none !important
  }
  `;
  window.open("https://yeezysupply.com");    and it didn't work

Comment: You need to change the `@match` to match the site you want to hide images on, as the answer says. You also can't use `window.open` with this, you have to use a userscript (or something similar), something that runs automatically on page load.

Comment: do I need to remove the // that you put in? Im confused on why you put those

Comment: No, the `//` is necessary - that needs to be in the userscript's metadata block. It's just as I typed it.

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work    // ==UserScript==
  // @name         Hide Images
  // @namespace    CertainPerformance
  // @version      1
  // @match        https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories/*
  // @grant        none
  // @run-at       document-start
  // ==/UserScript==

  document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
  img {
     display: none !important;
  }
  `;
  window.open("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories")

Comment: Like I just said in the previous comment, you cannot use `window.open`. As my answer says, *you have to create a userscript in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey*. `window.open` will initialize an entirely new page session, which will negate whatever you just did in the console.

Comment: Im not sure what that is do I have to install something?

Comment: Check out the answer: as it says, you have to `create a userscript in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey` Example, if you want Tampermonkey: https://www.google.com/search?q=tampermonkey